# I am not able to edit input fields in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

event.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { editEvent, eventDetail } from '../actions/event';

const EventDetail = () => {
 const { id } = useParams();
 const [updateEvent, setEvent] = useState();
 const EventRecord = useSelector((state) => state.eventDetail);
 const { loading, event, error } = EventRecord;
 const userRecords = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
 const { users } = userRecords;
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(eventDetail(id));
    setEvent(event);
 }, [id, dispatch]);
const handleChange = e => {
    console.log({ ...updateEvent, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    // setEvent({ ...updateEvent, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editEvent(updateEvent, id))
};

return (
    <div>
        {
            loading ? (
                <div> Loading... </div>
            ) : error ? (
                <div> {error} </div>
            ) : (
                        <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} >
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="name" className='mt-2'>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" value={event.name || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" name="description" value={event.description || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor='userId'>Assosicated User:</label>
                            <select value={event.userId || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} className="form-control" name='userId' >
                                
                            <option> Please Select </option>
                                {
                                    users.map((item) => {
                                        return (
                                            <option key={item.id} value={item.id} > {item.name} </option>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                            <Link to='/'> <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Back</button> </Link>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary float-right">Update Event</button>
                        </form>
                    )
        }
    </div>
 )
};

export default EventDetail;
```

I am not able to edit input fields even I have added onChange handle still it is not working and don't know what exactly issue is. I think it must work fine but is not don't know what exactly issue is rest everything is working fine. Any help will be appricated

Comment: I think you need to assign the onChange value to the state variable that you are tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you uisng logical OR here . you can use `defaultValue` attribute for shaoing null value in the input field
like

```
  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="description" defaultValue="" name="description" value={event.description} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
```

Comment: It worked for every case but not for select as if I give value in select it does not change and if I give defaultValue to it it does not show that value

Comment: add selected="selected" for your particular option which you want to make default

Answer (score 0):

in your inputs, replace value by defaultValue.

Comment: It worked for every case but not for select as if I give value in select it does not change and if I give defaultValue to it it does not show that value

Answer (score 0):

@Shubham, you have provided value=event.name or value=event.description. event is the state coming from useSelector.

Solution

1. You also have to provide your local state which you are updating in handleChange function i.e. updateEvent as value to input fields.

<input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" value={event.name || updateEvent.name || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />

2. Add the "name" in useState
   const [updateEvent, setEvent] = useState({name: ''});

Comment: It worked for every case but not for select as if I give value in select it does not change and if I give defaultValue to it it does not show that value